# PC wont boot another OS than Xubuntu 16

Tags: boot, windows-10, xubuntu

I'm trying to make an old PC useful. Is a Pentium 4 HT 3GHz, I did put a SATA HD and 3GB RAM, a nVidia GForce Fx 5200 128MB so it still can work ok. I chosen Ubuntu but the Unity interface is to heavy, but Xubuntu 16 32bits rocks!

But after a month I just can't install the graphic card drivers in Xubuntu 16, tried some tutorials, askubuntu, etc., it always end with an unresponsive OS died PC. People are talking a Windows 10 32bits runs ok, but the installer (DVD or USB) won't boot. After some tests, I realize nothing else is booting, no older Windows, not even an Ubuntu 14 that was installed before the Xubuntu. It will only boot with the same Xubuntu 16!

I think Xubuntu installer did something in my PC boot configuration but I can't find what, also don't know how to revert all motherboard configs so maybe I can start over and boot from Windows 10.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's a really old card, and terrible when it was even new. My guess is its no longer supported by anyone. maybe xubuntu works cause its using non composited graphics, and modern ubuntu and windows 10 don't.

Comment: I remember when it was a dream to have one card like this... anyway, there is drivers for 32bits Windows 8, Linux and Linux ARM (don't know the ARM difference). So booting problem might be due to graphic card? You sure? Any suggestions about a cheap and reliable replacement?

Comment: Sadly, I tend to get higher end cards. I'd see if I can get a 600 or 700 series nvidia card cheap.

Comment: My Windows 7 DVD is scratched, but I could boot from an old Windows XP media, so I have to sadly admit it is probably the video card fault. A nVidia 600 costs more than the rest of box (CPU, HDD, memories etc.) but it's something to consider, maybe I find some good deal.